Guava is transitively added to the artifact through testng added as a test dependency in maven
In my maven project, I have added testng with test scope.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 

I observed that class files from the guava version which testng depends on has ended up in my fat jar (I build the fat jar with maven-assembly-plugin).
Guava is not added directly as a dependency to my project, instead it is depended by protobuf-java-util dependency which I have added in my project. What I have observed is that the guava class files included in the fat jar are from the guava version depended by testng instead of the version depended by protobuf-java-util
When I excluded guava from testng, I can observe that the correct version of guava is picked up transitively from protobuf-java-util.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

Note that the module I am observing this is a nested sub module two levels deep from the root pom, and the testng dependency is in the root pom. I also observed that if I change the place which protobuf-java-util dependency is added, it gets precedence over the version derived from testng.
I also observed the same in the mvn:dependency-tree output, where guava is not shown under protobuf-java-util but under testng (with test scope), and when I added the exclusion above, it is correctly shown under protobuf-java-util.
What is the reason for this? From what I understood reading the maven documentation, the test scoped dependencies are only for test execution, so I wouldn't expect to see them in my fat jar.

Sadly, test dependencies are not just ignored when the JAR is build. Maven determines the scope and version of each (transitive) dependency, and in your case the scope compile won (as expected) but it seems that the test dependency's version won.
Generally, Maven dependency mediation is not something you should put much trust in. In many cases it is better to define <dependencyManagement> entries in your POM (or some parent POM or BOM) that fix a certain version so that you do not get surprises.
